# Website keep on loading - Selenium

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, webdriver

I have a problem on some websites, when i start them on selenium the main page keep on loading with no break and nothing happens (selenium waiting) only after i manually push the stop button in the browser selenium keep on going to next page but in the next page the same problem.

**Things i tried:**

- `driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0));`
- `driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0));`

**Browsers i used:**

- Internet Explorer
- FireFox
- PhantomJS
- Chrome

I thinking the problem is update from html to html 5 (the website always stays in connection with the server)

What can i do about it?

Thanks.

Comment: Ask whoever built this site to fix it.

Comment: good answer but did't helping... , i need some function that will stop browser from loading